# Weird behavior of printf() calls after usage of itoa() function

Tags: c

I am brushing up my C skills.I tried the following code for learning the usage of `itoa()` function:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main(){

    int x = 9;
    char str[] = "ankush";
    char c[] = "";

    printf("%s printed on line  %d\n",str,__LINE__);
    itoa(x,c,10);
    printf(c);
    printf("\n %s \n",str); //this statement is printing nothing
    printf("the current line is %d",__LINE__);
}
```

and i got the following output:

```
ankush printed on line 10
9
                      //here nothing is printed
the current line is 14
```

The thing is that if i **comment** the statement  `itoa(x,c,10);` from the code i get the above mentioned statement printed and got the following output:

```
ankush printed on 10 line

 ankush   //so i got it printed
the current line is 14
```

Is this a behavior of `itoa()` or i am doing something wrong.
Regards.

Comment: Your `itoa` call is writing into a buffer that's too small; there must be enough room for the target string AND the null terminator.  You're likely stomping on your other string in memory by overrunning on the `itoa` call.

Comment: `itoa` is writing to `c`, which can only store strings of length 0...

Comment: @Joe , i increased the size of `c` and problems vanished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As folks pointed out in the comments, the size of the array represented by the variable `c` is 1. Since C requires strings have a NULL terminator, you can only store a string of length 0 in `c`. However, when you call `itoa`, it has no idea that the buffer you're handing it is only 1 character long, so it will happily keep writing out digits into memory after `c` (which is likely to be memory that contains `str`).

To fix this, declare `c` to be of a size large enough to handle the string you plan to put into it, plus 1 for the NULL terminator. The largest value a 32-bit `int` can hold is 10 digits long, so you can use `char c[11]`.

To further explain the memory overwriting situation above, let's consider that `c` and `str` are allocated in contiguous regions on the stack (since they are local variables). So `c` might occupy memory address 1000 (because it is a zero character string plus a NULL terminator), and `str` would occupy memory address 1001 through 1008 (because it has 6 characters, plus the NULL terminator). When you try to write the string "9" into `c`, the digit 9 is put into memory address 1000 and the NULL terminator is put in memory address 1001. Since 1001 is the first address of `str`, `str` now represents a zero-length string (NULL terminator before any other characters). That's why you are getting the blank.

Comment: Hey, `str'  should occupy memory address 1001 through 1007.

Answer (score 0):

c must be a buffer long enough to hold your number.

Write

```
char c[20] ;
```

instead of

```
char c[] = "";
```